# checking wether a record exists or not before inserting it in a SQLite table

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I tried to implement select query for SQLite database of android app to check if id of movie exist or not in table to decide to insert it if it's not exist in table and to not insert it if it's already inserted before
so this is the code I wrote in MoviesProvider.java:

```
public class MoviesProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final int CODE_MOVIES = 200;
    public static final int CODE_MOVIES_WITH_ID = 201;

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    MoviesDbHelper mOpenHelper;

    public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {

        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = MoviesContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

        matcher.addURI(authority, MoviesContract.PATH_MOVIES, CODE_MOVIES);

        matcher.addURI(authority, MoviesContract.PATH_MOVIES + "/#", CODE_MOVIES_WITH_ID);

        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mOpenHelper = new MoviesDbHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Uri returnUri;

        switch (match) {

            case CODE_MOVIES: {

                String bookmarksMovieId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                String[] selectionArguments2 = new String[]{bookmarksMovieId};

                String Query = "SELECT * FROM" + MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME
                        + "WHERE" + MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_ID + "=" + selectionArguments2;
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
                if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
                    cursor.close();
                } else {

                    long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                    if (id > 0) {
                        returnUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
                    } else {
                        throw new android.database.SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        return returnUri;
    }

}
```

MoviesContract.java:

```
public class MoviesContract {

    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "giga.net.world.GN";

    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

    public static final String PATH_MOVIES = "shasha";

    public static final class MoviesEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                .appendPath(PATH_MOVIES)
                .build();

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "shasha";

        public static final String COLUMN_SHASHA_ID = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_SHASHA_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_SHASHA_CATEGORY = "category";

        public static Uri buildMoviesUriWithId(long id) {
            return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
                    .appendPath(Long.toString(id))
                    .build();
        }

    }
}
```

MoviesDBHelper.java:

```
public class MoviesDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "shasha.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

public MoviesDbHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        final String SQL_CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE =

                "CREATE TABLE " + MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +

                        MoviesContract.MoviesEntry._ID               + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "                 +
                        MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "                 +
                        MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MOVIES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }
}
```

and finally the onClick method:

```
public void onClickFavorite(View view) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_ID, MovieId);
        contentValues.put(MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_TITLE, MovieTitle);
        contentValues.put(MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_CATEGORY, MovieCategory);

        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        if (uri != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

the problem is when I click on favorite button inside any movie the app is just crashed and I get the following message from logcat:

> Could not execute method for android:onClick Caused By : SQL(query)
>   error or missing database.(near "FROMshashaWHEREid": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT *
>   FROMshashaWHEREid=[Ljava.lang.String;@cdbe7d7)

why I get the id like this:

> WHEREid=[Ljava.lang.String;@cdbe7d7)

Comment: @Kling Klang I add the spaces now but the app still crush and I get this error: SQL(query) error or missing database.(unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@b2c12b3" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM shasha WHERE id = [Ljava.lang.String;@b2c12b3)

Comment: Your'e not getting an actual string. You're only getting the **id** of the string resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add some spaces on your query build string.

```
FROM**shasha**WHEREid
```

It is on this part,

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM" + MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME
                    + "WHERE" +
```

Comment: I add the spaces now but the app still crush and I get this error: SQL(query) error or missing database.(unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@b2c12b3" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM shasha WHERE id = [Ljava.lang.String;@b2c12b3)

Comment: This is a new problem, but the previous one that you have is resolved. ;), It seems that your uri is empty.

Comment: Anyway, based on your error `SQL(query) error or missing database`, you need to check if your pointing to the corect database.

Comment: okay thanks man I will try to solve the new problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to add spaces between every word:

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.COLUMN_SHASHA_ID + " = " + selectionArguments2;
```